# Como enviar una imagen desde un cliente React-Nativo a un servidor Node.js

Tags: nodejs, react-native, multer

Estoy intentando mandar una imagen desde react-nativo, usando typescript, a un servidor node.js que usa Multer para procesar la imagen. Tengo entendido que Multer genera un objeto file, el cual tiene, entre otras propiedades, la propiedad "path". Mi problema es que despues de mandar la imagen desde el cliente, quiero acceder a req.file en el servidor a fin de subir esta imagen a un S3 bucket. Sin embargo, req.file es undefined. Me gustaria saber cual es la manera correcta de mandar un archivo/imagen desde react-nativo a un servidor.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
//uploadImage.tsx
import { LOCAL_SERVER } from '@env';
import axios from 'axios'
import { useState } from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native'
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
const Profile : React.FC = ()=>{
    
        const [picture, setPicture] = useState<string>('')
       
      
        const pickImage = async ():Promise<string|boolean> => {
          // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
          let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1,
          });
      
          console.log(result);
      
          if (!result.cancelled) {
          
            setPicture(result.uri)
           
            
            return result.uri
          }
          return false
        };

        const sendPictureToServer = async () => {
            const formData = new FormData()
            const data = {uri:picture, type:"image/jpeg", name:'profile', filename:'afiletest'};
            formData.append('file', data)
            formData.append('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
           
            await axios.post(LOCAL_SERVER+'/dashboard/chooseProfilePic', formData, {
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'muLtipart/form-data'}
            })
            
        }
    return(
            <View>
                <Text>Change profile picture</Text>
                <Button title = 'select' onPress={pickImage}/>
                <Button title='send' onPress={sendPictureToServer}/>

            </View>
    )
}

export default Profile
```

Este es mi archivo de rutas

```
const {Router} = require('express')
const router = Router()
const controller = require('../controller/dashboard')
const multer= require('multer')
const upload= multer({dest:'uploads'})



router.post('/chooseProfilePic',upload.single('file') , controller.chooseProfilePicture)

module.exports = router
```

Este es el controlador donde quiero acceder a req.file una vez que el archivo ha sido procesado por Multer

```
chooseProfilePicture : async(req, res) => {
        console.log('tghis is the file',req.file)
        console.log('this is the body',req.body)  
    },
```

Que es lo que espero que suceda al llamarse la funcion de arriba? Qu se imprima en la consola lo siguiente:

```
tghis is the file {
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'profile_portfolio.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: 'uploads',
  filename: '6a81e0c9f5ada0262bd00dd488ab31bc',
  path: 'uploads\\6a81e0c9f5ada0262bd00dd488ab31bc',
  size: 34382
}
```

Que es lo que sucede:

```
tghis is the file undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de utilizar fetch o axios, lo que funcionó para mi fue usar la librería  expo-file-system, la cual tiene el metodo uploadAsync().unicamente modifiqué el lado del cliente, no fue necesario modificar nada del lado del servidor.  Asi es como quedó el codigo usando expo-file-system:

```
const sendPictureToServer = async()=>{
  
    
    const response = await FileSystem.uploadAsync('RemoteUrl/dashboard/chooseProfilePic' ,image,{
        
        fieldName: 'file',
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        uploadType: FileSystem.FileSystemUploadType.MULTIPART,

    })
    
   }
```

Notese que en la documentacion de expo-file-system, se rcomienda definir el upload type asi:

```
uploadType: FileSystem.FileSystemUploadType.BinaryContent,
```

Lo anterior, produjó que mi archivo siguiera llegando como indefinido al servidor. Por lo cual cambie BinaryContent por MULTIPART.

Answer (score 0):

tengo un proyecto similar y me ha funcionado para obtener la información que requieres, en mi archivo de rutas tengo así:

```
router.post("/", uploads.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  const info = req.file; // prueba
  console.log({ info });  // prueba
  controller.showInfo(req.file);
...
...
...
```

En mi archivo controlador recibirá la información de file que introducimos en el router y así la podremos manejar

```
function showInfo(info) {
  console.log(info);
  console.log(info.fieldname);
  console.log(info.originalname);
  console.log(info.encoding);
  console.log(info.mimetype);
  console.log(info.destination);
  console.log(info.filename);
  console.log(info.path);
  console.log(info.size);
}
```

Espero te sirva.